# Redirect back to same page (with variables) on form submit in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

On my page events.index, I first display a list of events for the logged on user.

On my index page I have a form with option/select to let the user select and display the events of another user. When he submits that form, I would like my index function (controller) to use the $user_id value (from the form) and display the events.index page again, but for events of that selected user.

I'm not sure what would be the best approach:

- Set a session variable to keep the user_id value? Not sure how to do that with a form.
- Submit the form with a get method (and get an ugly ?user_id=1 URL)
- Change my index route to accept the post method (although I already have that post/events route taken (by Route::post('events', 'EventsController@store'))

Not sure what would be a clean way to do this:

My route for events/index:

```
Route::get('events', [
'as' => 'event.index',
'uses' => 'EventsController@index'
]);
```

Events Controller

```
public function index()
{
    // How to get the $user_id value from form?

    if (empty($user_id)) 
    {
        $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    }

    $events = Event::where('events.user_id','=','$user_id');        
    $users  = User::all();

    return view('events.index')->with(['events' => $events])->with(['users' => $users]);
}
```

View for index

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'events.index', 'method' => 'get']) !!}

    <select id="user_id" name="user_id">
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>

{!! Form::submit('Show events for this user') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}   


@foreach($events as $event)
     ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'd use option #2 as in my opinion this is the cleanest way: User #1 looks at events of User #2, so User #1 should be on an URL like ?user=2

Comment: You could just use javascript to do the filtering, unless you need the filter to be saved globally, e.g., select user A and then other pages will also filter by user A. In that case I would use an ajax post to save the user filter value and have all your queries filter by that if it's set.

Comment: @jakub_jo not that its not clean, but it doesn't generate a pretty url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `user_id` from a `Request` object, you just need to inject it in the index method:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->get('user_id') ?: Auth::id();

    $events = Event::where('events.user_id','=','$user_id')->get();

    $users  = User::all();

    return view('events.index')->with(['events' => $events])->with(['users' => $users]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but does that mean that my route needs to go from `Route::get` to `Route::post` ?

Comment: ok, I guess what I meant is that, to hide the ugly part of the URL (?user_id=1) , I still have to change my form and route to Post

Comment: if thats your intention then you can simply add another line to your routes file `Route::post('events', 'EventsController@index');` or change your existing definition `Route::any(...` .In my opinion route parameters, when required, are not ugly at all and save from a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: I can change `Route::get('events', 'EventsController@index')`  to `Route::post('events', 'EventsController@index')`, but the thing is I also have the following route : `Route::post('events', 'EventsController@store')`, so they don't work together because they have the same name. Thanks for your help

Comment: then you will have to make do with ugly url :)